# There was a mismatch between the processor architecture

Tags: windows-store-apps, processor

I am currently building a Windows store application using visual studio 2012 in 4.5.1 framework

I have added the reference PresentationCore.dll for the 'bitmapImage'  and i am confronted by an error saying 'There has been a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being build MSIL & processor architecure of presentationCore'

I have tried the method concerning the use of the configuration manager and still seems to not work, would anybody be able to give me any in sight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PresentationCore.dll is from the Windows Presentation Foundation. You cannot add a WPF DLL to a Windows Store app as you will be mixing between .NETFramework (desktop) and .NETCore (WinRT).